# Force pinned web app to retrieve latest code

Tags: ios, web-applications, jqmobi

I have built a web app using jqmobile which runs perfectly from within the browser but when I pin to the home screen it behaves differently.

It's as if it's still using an older version of the code. I've tried closing the application (double clicking home and deleting the icon) then removing the icon from home and re-adding it but it exhibits exactly the same behaviour.

Is there a way to purge the old version and force it to retrieve the latest version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a delay of 5 mins or so for external code libraries, longer for external css.